# UWP disable WebView's scroll event inside ScrollViewer

Tags: webview, windows-phone, uwp, scrollviewer, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to disable the scrolling event of the WebView which is located inside a ScrollViewer which is done with success.

```
 private async void webview_NavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args) {
     // set the webview height and disable he scrolling 
     sender.Height = int.Parse(await sender.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new[] { "document.body.scrollHeight.toString()" }));
     await sender.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';" });
     ...
}
```

Now, the problem that comes in surface is that when scrolling the view in a real device, it seems that the touch events of the WebView overrides the touch events of the ScrollViewer.
The desired outcome is to keep the touch events of WebView active since it contains clickable links, but in addition the scroll event of the ScrollViewer override any other scroll event.

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer"
    Height="auto">    
    <StackPanel Height="auto" Orientation="Vertical">
        <Image  x:Name="eventImage"
                Height="180"
                Margin="30,30,30,30"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Top" />

        <TextBlock x:Name="eventDate"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"                                                        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
                TextWrapping="Wrap" />

        <WebView x:Name="webview"
                Margin="0,0,0,0"
                NavigationCompleted="webview_NavigationCompleted"
                              ScrollViewer.ZoomMode="Disabled" />

        <ListView Name="m_ListView"
                MinWidth="300"
                MinHeight="200"
                Margin="0,0,0,80"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Thanks in advance. Waiting for any response.

Comment: I had the similar problem and we generated HTML code wich includes `Image`, `TextBlock` and `ListView`

Comment: Thank you for your reply Andrii, it seems to be a good proposal. Though, i'd prefer keeping it native, since on ListView items there are options to send an email, make a phone call etc.

Comment: we created list items with js code which invokes with required params. and I parse params via `ScriptNotify` event

Comment: This sounds promissing. I'll give it a try. Thanks